# ShellExperienceHost.exe Adware removal - Solved was Chrome notification

Tags: windows-10, malware, adware

I have some adware I can't get rid of. I'd appreciate any advice. I have tried Malware Bytes and all kinds of manual methods to get rid of it.

ShellExperienceHost.exe as I understand it can be used for adware. I have used ProcessExplorer to identify the task.

[Process explorer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK7ir.png)

You can see the command line is:
"C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe" -ServerName:App.AppXtk181tbxbce2qsex02s8tw7hfxa9xb3t.mca

Very suspicious. If I kill the task, the window disappears and immediately reappears showing the same ad.

[Adware image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C5AA.png)

I have searched the computer for .mca files.
I have searched all files by date modified (for when I think it was co-installed with another App)
I have searched regsitry for all ShellExperienceHost.exe entries. None match the above .mca file and I can't tell what other registry keys are valid or not. All seem suspecious as they have these random character names (which could be completely valid).
I have uninstalled the Software that I suspect loaded this. (never saw it before, popped up 1 second after app was installed.)

Please, any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

New information. The process itself is also on my other computer, killing it also causes it to spawn again, but no sound or ad comes up. Although ProcessExplorer identifies the window as being part of ShellExperienceHost.exe it would seem there is something else going on. The file dates and times on ShellExperienceHost.exe on the suspect computer are correct, so I don't beleive the file has been tampered with. I will keep hunting.

Comment: Total AV didn't find it either. Pops up with a sound too... I hate this adware.

Comment: I did some googling around, and as it seems, ShellExperienceHost isn't a type of adware, but belongs to the Windows core.
That explains why no AV or adware removal tools can find anything, and you would be extremely ill-advised to remove it.

However, it seems that this could either be related to some AV programs or something going haywire in the Windows Store.

Comment: I know the ShellExperienceHost belongs to windows, but I suspect it has been hijacked. The ServerName:App line suggest you can pass things to the .exe. I think ShellExperienceHost is responsible for the Start Menu. It's frustration as I can't kill the task (re-spawns immediately with sound and new ad). I have a workaround for the moment, I use ProcessExplorer to set the task priority to "Idle". This has stopped it popping up. This has not seemed to affect anything else in the system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like those are Google Chrome notifications.

Check Settings --> Advanced --> Site Settings --> Notifications.

Check what's in the allow list.

Comment: That sir was the answer! answersafrica was in in allow list. Thank you so much. I feel a bit silly for spending so much time going down the wrong road, but it's solved now! Thanks  again

Comment: I got this today with the domain of the Adware being `pl.soringpcrepair.com`. Thanks for this!

Comment: I got this today with the non-existent domain allowsuccess.org. Thanks. It took a while for me to find this post, but it worked! I had the same experience with Windows Shell Experience Host, which I couldn't remove or it would pop right back. Is it possible to remove the allowsuccess.org reference completely? It seems that it is now sitting there, although I disabled it.

Answer (score 0):

That is wrong answer. You gave image of chrome notification that is chrome notification.
But question is about virus.
That is a virus if antivirus show it as such. Where you got this windows installation?

Also could be that chrome is inficeted with plugin, that gives windows popups thrue this infected file.

Im not sure it is for windows notification system.

The answer you accepted just answers about where is comming from this popup, or as so identifies windows hijacked popup manager, that could inform that virus is making popups from chrome or its from windows making false info that its from chrome.

Try saving all your bookmarks by syncing profiles in settings.

Then removing all profiles and all chrome uninstalling and removing files of chrome. Delete C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google and in program files for 32 and 64 bit google chrome folders

Then reinstalling chrome and logging back in to get bookmarks and virus extensions back. Check what kind of extensions you have. Chrome sometimes let some chrome shop extensions be with viruses very very rarelly and automatically removing them for all infected. But if you installed manually some extensions knowing manually or some virus did it, then on sync i think you wont have thouse extensions anymore.